# How To Determine If Azure Blob Is Different Than Current File (C# / .Net Core)?

Tags: c#, azure, file, .net-core, azure-blob-storage

I only want to upload a file to Azure Blob Storage if the blob that it will be overwriting (the blob file) is different than the current file (the one being uploaded).

Does anyone have any suggestions for this functionality using C# / .Net Core?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple ways to do this depending on what you can do with the current file.

1. Simplest way is to just upload without worrying about whether or not it will change. If it's the same, it will stay, if not it will get replaced with the new version.

Based on your question, this is probably not an option for you. The next thing to check would be the [blob properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-properties-metadata?tabs=dotnet). You can let Blob store use default values, or you can override them when you upload the blob.

You can take a look at them in the portal and they will look something like this:

```
LAST MODIFIED   11/20/2020, 1:28:22 PM
CREATION TIME   7/31/2019, 11:44:55 AM
VERSION ID  -
TYPE    Block blob
SIZE    64 B
ACCESS TIER N/A
ACCESS TIER LAST MODIFIED   N/A
SERVER ENCRYPTED    true
ETAG    0x8D88D820FE0B5E4
CONTENT-TYPE    application/octet-stream
CONTENT-MD5 vfS7mlI8PCeeG2yXyUQ25A==
LEASE STATUS    Unlocked
LEASE STATE Available
```

To get them in C#, run `BlobProperties properties = await blob.GetPropertiesAsync();`

2. If your new file is the existing file + edits, then the LastModified property might be enough to tell if they are different.
3. The MD5 hash of the existing and new file is also a good choice for a comparison. Hashes aren't strictly unique, but they are usually unique enough to tell if a file has been changed.
4. If you are in control of creating the blob as well as updating it, you also have the option of setting custom properties on the blob. That would allow you to set something on the blob that you would be able to track to see if the content has changed. The same `GetPropertiesAsync()` method retrieves the metadata dictionary, and setting it is done by creating a `Dictionary<string, string>` and passing that to `blob.SetMetadataAsync(metadata);`
5. Absolute worst case would be downloading the existing blob and running a compare on the two documents. Unless there is some reason I absolutely had to do this, if 2-4 didn't work for me, I would choose the first option and only use this as a last resort.